# Merge multiple pg_search_scope and track which one give return the answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having multiple pg_search_scope with different thresholds, and I would like to call this in a controller that will return the result from such scopes, but I would like to know which one of those pg_search_scope returned the result. Any hints on how to do it ? 
I thought to have:

```rb
(Article.pg_scope1(params[:query])+
Article.pg_scope2(params[:query])+
Article.pg_scope3(params[:query])).first
```

But this will not tell me which one did return the answer.

Comment: To clarify, the objective for me is that I would like to know/track the origin of the response given by the controller in a very Rails way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any ways to get the name of scope directly from scoped relation.
So, I think, the easiest way to solve your issue is:

```rb
(
  [
    {scope_name: :first, data: Article.pg_scope1(params[:query])}, 
    {scope_name: :second, data: Article.pg_scope2(params[:query])}, 
    {scope_name: :third, data: Article.pg_scope3(params[:query])} 
  ]
).find { |scope| scope[:data].present? }
```

In that case you will receive one of hashes with scope_name with data inside, like a

```
=> {scope_name: :second, data: Article.pg_scope2(params[:query])}
```

Or you can use array inside array

```rb
result = (
 [
   [:first, Article.pg_scope1(params[:query])],
   [:second, Article.pg_scope2(params[:query])],
   [:third, Article.pg_scope3(params[:query])],
 ].find {|scope| scope[1].present? }
)
```

And access to result data by calling `result[1]`, and scope_name by calling `result[0]`

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I posted my question, I come up with a solution, that is kinda convoluted, but might doing the job as well.

```rb
queries = {
  "scope1": Article.pg_scope1(params[:query]),
  "scope2": Article.pg_scope2(params[:query]),
  "scope3": Article.pg_scope3(params[:query])
}

engines_with_content=queries.reject{|k,v| v.empty?}.keys
```

Then, to get the results I can do `queries[engines_with_content.first]` to access the `ActiveRecord::Relation`

I wish there was a way to parallelize the queries in a safe way.

Comment: Just notice, for keys in the hash, it's better to use symbols instead of strings